# Pinia not initilizing in router for vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, pinia

I have been trying to use Pinia for state management in my vue application. I've been running into the issue where pinia is being used before its initialised in the main.js folder.

This is the routes file.

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import {useUserStore} from '../stores/user'

const store = useUserStore()

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/', 
      name: 'login',
      component: () => import('../views/LoginView.vue')

    },
    {
      path: '/Dash',
      name: 'dash',
      component: () => import('../views/authed/DashView.vue'),
      // beforeEnter: (to, from) => {
      // }
    },
    {
      path: '/Register',
      name: 'register',
      component: () => import('../views/RegisterView.vue')
    }
  ]
})



export default router
```

This is the place where is store the data. user.js

```
import { ref, computed, watch } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios'



export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
    const user = ref ({
        name: "",
        token: "",
        auth: false,
        
    })


    // if (localStorage.getItem('user')) {
    //     user.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
    // }
    // watch(
    //     user,
    //         (userVal) => {
    //             localStorage.setItem('User', JSON.stringify(userVal))
    //         },
    //         { deep: true}
    // )

    const setAuth = (newToken, successAuth, authedName) => {
        user.value.token = newToken
        user.value.auth = successAuth
        user.value.name = authedName
    }

    const checkAuth = () => {
        try {
            const response =  axios.post('api/get-user', {}, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${user.value.token}`
                }
            })
            .then(({ data: userData }) => {
                console.log('USER IS AUTHED')
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
    return {
        user,
        setAuth,
        checkAuth,
    }
},
{
    persist: true
})
```

This is the main.js file.

```
import { createApp, watch } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import piniaPluginPersistedstate from 'pinia-plugin-persistedstate'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import "bootstrap"
import axios from 'axios'

import './assets/main.css'
const pinia = createPinia()

// if (localStorage.getItem('user')) {
//     pinia.user.value = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('user'))

// }

// watch(
//     pinia.state,
//     (state) => {
//         localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(state))
//     },
//     { deep: true }
// )


const app = createApp(App)
pinia.use(piniaPluginPersistedstate)
app.use(pinia)
app.use(router, axios)

app.mount('#app')
```

This is my error...

```
Uncaught Error: []: getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
    const pinia = createPinia()
    app.use(pinia)
This will fail in production.
    at useStore (pinia.js?v=3c6f7703:1256:13)
    at index.js?t=1658100067018:5:9
```

The error happens when I add to the router file, I need to use it here so I can authenticate users to use certain routes.

```
import {useUserStore} from '../stores/user'


store = useUserStore()
```

This is the edit I've made to the main.js file from the first answer, however moving the place I import the file hasn't made a difference still getting the same error.

```
import { createApp, watch } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import piniaPluginPersistedstate from 'pinia-plugin-persistedstate'
import App from './App.vue'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import "bootstrap"
import axios from 'axios'

import './assets/main.css'
const pinia = createPinia()




const app = createApp(App)
pinia.use(piniaPluginPersistedstate)
app.use(pinia)
import router from './router'

app.use(router, axios)

app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: what is all that commented code? Which line of your code have you determined is the cause of the issue?

Comment: The commented code was going to be the way that the data persisted through the app, however I found that it was much simpler to use piniaPluginPersistedState. I left it commented in case I wanted to use it in the future if I ran into problems with piniaPluginPersistedState plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your main.js file when you `import router from './router'` this line will be excute `const store = useUserStore()` at this time Pinia is not define yet.

Comment: Genius sir! I knew it was something like this but I couldn't see where... I'll try to import the router after creating Pinia instance...

Comment: I've now moved the import router part after doing app.use(pinia) but it still doesn't work, getting same error.

Comment: After reading the docs again, I've figured it out! Adding this to the router.js file enabled me to run the store. router.beforeEach((to) => {
  // ✅ This will work because the router starts its navigation after
  // the router is installed and pinia will be installed too
  const store = useStore()

})

Comment: Nice work, my man.

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/723, https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html#single-page-applications